# How to use django paginator page range for displaying the first 10 numbers not all?

Tags: django, pagination

I want to change the blow script to show just the first 10 page numbers. Now it shows all page numbers. Could you please tell me how to change it? I tried several ways but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated!

```
 {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" or forloop.last %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if is_paginated %}
        <div class="row">

            <ul class="pagination pagination-md ">

                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">«</a></li>

                {% endif %}
                {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
                    {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }}</span></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}{% if currentCategory %}&category={{ currentCategory }}
                        {% endif %}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}

                {% if page_obj.has_next %}

                    <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">»</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="disabled"><span>»</span></li>
                {% endif %}

            </ul>

        </div>
    {% endif %}

</div>
```

Comment: How about adding a `{% if i < 10 %}` in your template or the slice filter `paginator.page_range|slice:":10"`

Comment: Many thanks Resley! This (paginator.page_range|slice:":10")  worked.